# Check if image exists in folder Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried creating folder in root project named **images**  as well as **assets** folder with child images like **assets/images**

on button click i want to check if specific image file exists in folder. i have tried both ways

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            shekitxva = examQuestionList[900].Question;
            // Check if the image exists
            if (File('assets/images/bg.png').existsSync()) {
              print('The image exists in the specified folder.');
            } else {
              print('The image does not exist in the specified folder.');
            }
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: const Text("გაზრდა"),
        ),
```

**File('assets/images/bg.png').existsSync()**
neither
**File('images/bg.png').existsSync()** seems to work as i always get false

this is my pubspec

```
flutter:    
uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - images/bg.png
  - assets/
  - assets/images/bg.png
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to check image exist or not is that

```
bool checkImage () {
   try {
      final bundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
      await bundle.load('assets/images/bg.png');
      AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png');
      return true; /// Exist
   } catch (e) {
        return false; //Not Exist
   )
}
```

[source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70010)

Answer (score 0):

The path you pass to the constructor of a file looks for the file on the device, not in the project directory.

Assets you list in your pubspec.yaml file should always exist, but if you want to check whether or not the file exists, use the rootBundle:

```dart
Future<bool> assetExists(String path) async {
  try {
    await rootBundle.loadString(path);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Rohan Jariwala

i modified your code and got it working

```
Future<bool> checkImage() async {
try {
  final bundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
  await bundle.load('assets/images/bg.png');
  AssetImage('assets/images/bg.png');
  return Future<bool>.value(true);

  /// Exist
} catch (e) {
  return Future<bool>.value(false);
}
```

}

and then call the function

```
var value = await checkImage();
print(value);
```